# Issue on IDE Eclipse performance (bug or feature)?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to adjust the speed of my Eclipse IDE, 
I've even made the following changes to eclipse.ini

```
-Xms1000m
-Xmx1500m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

However, there is one thing I can't really get. 
When I open 2 different HTML files (index.html and index.html from another project) 50-80 LOC, it takes Eclipse 5-6 seconds to switch between them. 
On the other hand, when I'm dealing with 500+ LOC Java classes, Eclipse switches between them in 1-1,5 seconds. 
Eclipse.exe, eclipse folder and my workspace are included to exceptions in Antivirus software.

Please explain me what's happening here and is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial Eclipse Juno release contained some bugs that could cause editor switching to be very slow; I think the bugs have been mostly fixed in the SR releases.
See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391868

Note that 4.2.2 (Juno SR2) will be available very soon (by the end of this week or beginning of next).

Answer (score 0):

The first time you open HTML/XHTML files it may take a while because Eclipse loads most of the parser/validation data and tools at that time. Parsing and validating HTML/CSS/Scripts takes more time than parsing Java files.

Comment: I'm asking about switching between already opened simply HTML files.

Comment: do you use the WTP plugin, how big are your html files ?

Comment: WTP 3.4 installed, my html-files are about 80-100 lines and my classes are 500+ lines. Why switching between classes are 1-1,5 sec, while between html-s are 5-6 sec ?

Comment: I only experience a delay at first opening, not sure what causes the issue in your case sorry... try on a separate Eclipse installation and compare.